# Отправка email в Android

Tags: android, email

Я хочу сделать приложение, которое делает рассылку писем на определённые email-адреса, введённые пользователем. При этом для того, чтобы ограничить количество телодвижений пользователя и избавить его от необходимости аутентификации в почтовом клиенте, я хочу отправлять эти письма со своего электронного ящика (и, если это имеет значение, не корпоративного, а личного). Насколько это безопасно и кошерно?

*P.S.* Существует ли возможность скрыть этот адрес отправителя для получателей в отправленных письмах?

Comment: для этого достаточно своего сервера(любой хостинг), api на любом языке и установленного почтового сервера. Безопасность решит ssl и прямы руки конечно же. Либо есть полно таких сервисов с уже готовым api(но имхо это глупо). Но! опять же имхо - не нужно избавлять юзера от этого, это не так уж и сложно реализовать и по времени у это занимает секунды.

Comment: Не понятен смысл затеи - Вы дарите пароль от личной почты всем желающим, и пишете приложение для более комфортного спама с Вашего ящика?

Comment: @woesss, просто в Google Play такие приложения существуют... Вот меня и интересует вопрос, насколько такая стратегия правильна)

Comment: 1.Ни в коем случае не использовать почту, которой пользуетесь сами (зарегить новый ящик - плёвое дело)! 2. Не "вшивать" и не передавать пароль от ящика в приложение (увод пароля сломает приложение у всех юзеров разом). В общем либо авторизовать юзера и слать от его имени, либо через сервер. Сторонний сервис (хоть товарищ и выразился "глупо") - это наименьшие затраты в реализации и адрес отправителя с Вами никак не связан.